# Redirect list of subdomains to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have many subdomains on `oldsite.example` that I want to 301 redirect to newsite.com. However some subdomains should stay at `oldsite.example` and the redirected subdomains follow no regex-able pattern, making wildcards irrelevant.

I'd like an expression where I can write a list something like `sub1,page,boop` which would set up redirects for all the following

```
sub1.oldsite.example -> sub1.newsite.example
page.oldsite.example -> page.newsite.example
beep.oldsite.example -> beep.newsite.example
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Have you tried anything to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rewrite rule that can be used to do this:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub1|page|boop)\.oldsite\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%1.newsite.example/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

- `RewriteEngine on` enables rewrite rules and only needs to be used once in `.htaccess`
- `RewriteCond` specifies a condition that needs to be met before the rewrite rule is activated
- `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the domain name
- `(sub1|page|boop)` your list of subdomains in a capturing group
- `[NC]` - case insensitive
- `^/?(.*)$` matches every page on those subdomains with a capturing group
- `https://%1.newsite.example/$1` the new URL with substitutions of the capturing groups from the condition and the rule
- `[R=301]` - 301 permanent redirect
- `[L]` - Last rewrite rule (so that others don't get triggered after this one matches)
- `[QSA]` - Query string append - preserve any parameters on the URL

Comment: You don't strictly need the `QSA` flag here, since the query string is preserved by default.